# Как можно постепенно загружать картинку из stream?

Tags: javascript, потоки-данных

У меня есть поток в котором я читаю изображение.
Я могу его отобразить, когда весь файл загружен.
Мне достаточно:

- Объединить все части кода,
- Создать blob объект,
- Сделать на него ссылку и указать в `srс`

```
  let blob = new Blob([concat(arrays)], {'type': 'image/png'});
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  image.src = `${url}`
```

Есть ли возможность отображать уже загруженную часть картинки ?

Например:

- Создать blob

```
let blob = new Blob([array], {'type': 'image/png'});
```

- А когда приходит следующий буфер с данными дописать его в этот объект ?

Я могу так же в процессе blob добавить, и тогда он постепенно будет загружаться, но мне кажется это не оптимальный вариант.